# coloquei o CDN, como eu faço para escrever o código?

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

sou iniciante em programação e estou com essa dúvida, coloquei o CDN 
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/rivescript@latest/dist/rivescript.min.js"></script>` 
para instalar o [rivescript](https://www.rivescript.com), mas agora eu queria saber como faço para escrever meu código com essa lib, eu uso outro script src e coloco o link dentro do JS? não sei como usar!

Comment: Dá uma lida na documentação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz assim amigo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/rivescript@latest/dist/rivescript.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var bot = new RiveScript();
  
  console.log(bot);
  
  // aqui faz alguma coisa com esse plugin...
  
</script>
```

Comment: valeu! daqui há 8 minutos aceito tua resposta